# How to read Vim keystroke syntax?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to learn Vim and I'm seeing a lot of documentation use syntax like
`<C-v>`. Is there a general guide on how to read this correctly?

I've attached an example SO post below that uses this syntax:

> #### [Vim multiline editing like in sublimetext?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11790464/68587)
>
> Do yourself a favor by droping the Windows compatibility layer. The normal shortcut for entering Visual-Block mode is `<C-v>`.

Comment: Are you asking about how you would read the directions out loud in English, or about what key(s) it is instructing you to press?

Comment: Shameless plug: If you're interested in Vim, checkout the [vi.se] sister site.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From within Vim, `:help <>` has a short overview of the notation Vim uses with a few examples, including:

```
<C-G>            CTRL-G
<C-LeftMouse>    Control- left mouse click
```

`:help key-notation` or `:help keycodes` will bring up a more thorough list of conventions used within Vim's documentation (and typically copied by Vim users as well) to refer to various keys. One of the lines has this:

```
notation    meaning       equivalent   decimal   value(s)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

<C-...>     control-key                          *control* *ctrl* *<C-*
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a general guide on vims documentation syntax. But from my experience < C-v> is equivalent to (ctrl + v).

This can be seen for example in this cheat sheet.
https://gist.github.com/awidegreen/3854277

And in this question on SO 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289681/why-does-c-a-ctrla-not-work-under-gvim-on-windows